# Rounded rect button in NSToolbar

Tags: xcode, nstoolbar

How do you change the width of a button in a tool bar on Mac?  I can change the width in interface builder but it only updates if the width is larger than the current size.  If I try to make it smaller it doesn't change in tool bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you found an answer yet, but I was recently looking to do this as well for a popup button. The answer is to create the button outside the toolbar first. Then once you create it you can drag it onto the toolbar area and it will be added as a toolbar item.

For example, I created a popup button on my main window and set it to the width that I wanted. Then I opened the toolbar section and dragged that button onto it... and it worked.

Good luck.